# Tab indicator adjusted according to the text materialize

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I would like to leave the tab indicator according to the size of the text.

Example:

[image]

[image]

Should I do this with javascript? I'm using the Angular.

My code html:

```
<div class="row ranking-wrapper">
    <div class="col s12 tab-cor no-pd">
      <ul class="tabs ranking-tabs tabs-fixed-width tabs-icon">
        <li class="tab col s3">
          <a href="#ranking-nivel1">
            <div>
              <i class="material-icons estrela-tabs tabs-icon">star</i>
            </div>
            <div>
              {{NIVEL1}}
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
</div>
```

My css

```
.tabs .indicator {
    background-color:#f6a20d;
    height: 5px !important;
} 

.tab-cor{
    background-color: #5c4438;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #f6a20d;
}

.tabs-icon{
    font-size: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tabs-icon i {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: -15px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: We need the CSS as well

Comment: Ok, now i added css

Answer (score 1):

You should use `line-height` in the `a` element:

```
.tabs a {
    line-height: 30px;
}
```